# Django-Rest-Framework, POST operation: fields is not empty but DRF says is required

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework

Well, i have this **model**:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("nom", unique=True, max_length=255)
    sonarQube_URL = models.CharField("Url SonarQube", max_length=255,
                                 blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and this **serializer**:

```
class ApplicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nom = serializers.CharField(source='name', required=True, allow_blank=True)
    url_sonarqube = serializers.CharField(source='sonarQube_URL', required=False)
    flows = FlowSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ('id', 'nom', 'url_sonarqube', 'flows')
```

**My view** is simple:

```
class ApplicationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Application.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApplicationSerializer
```

I use this model of permissions in my **settings.py**:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
    'TEST_REQUEST_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.MultiPartRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer'
    )
}
```

When I use POST operation on DRF interface (in HTML Form), I filled all the fields of the application Item. As you can see, "required" parameter of "nom" is set to True. And, this is the problem: even if 'nom' is not empty, DRF says "this field is required!". So, I can't POST a new application item.
I don't understand why it not works... Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got is related to the `Django Model(Application)`. It was failing in model level not in serializer level. Add `null=True` and `blank=True` to `name` field in `Application` model.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep your code in English, you can use Django's i18n to translate stuff, also use blank and null for your name field:

```
class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    sonarqube_url = models.CharField(_('SonarQube URL'), max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class ApplicationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Application
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'sonarqube_url')
```

Let's save flows for later as you don't even have a model relation for them.